# How do i convert world direction to local direction?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, matrix, vector, glm-math

I have the world positions of two objects (A and B) and the rotation of A. How do i calculate the local direction from A to B from the perspective of A?

Position = x, y, z
Rotation = x, y, z, w

I think the world direction should be:

```
dir = B  - A
magnitude = dir.magnitude()
direction = dir / magnitude
```

Not sure how local direction would work?

Comment: You've tagged this with both [glm-math] and [unity game entine], about which are you asking? and what language is this, unity uses C# but GLM appears to be C++

Comment: Despite this, can you not simply multiply your world direction by your rotation quaternion (as a side note I have no idea why this value would be useful, the direction from A to B in local space seems to me to be pretty meaningless)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that, you can use worldToLocalMatrix from GameObject A

```
var dir = A.transform.worldToLocalMatrix.MultiplyVector(dir);
```

or use Quaternions to calculate that manually like that:

```
var dir = Quaternion.Inverse(A.transform.rotation) * dir;
```

The results should be quite similar, except second way would ignore lossyScale (which is probably desired effect anyway)

I'm not sure what result Type are you expecting, as "direction" can be represented by either Vector3 forward or Quaterion rotation, but you can use

```
Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
```

to convert from Vector3 to Quaterion and it should work fine most of the times

Comment: I dont have access to any of those functions. What are the implementations of those methods? or something translated to the glm library.

Comment: Oh, sry you said A and B are objects but these are probably Vector3 based on your code. You should use transform taken from MonoBehaviour or GameObject